# How to express "Now, ..." in Chinese (the usage of "now" to draw attention to a particular statement)?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, word-requests, adverbs

In the following example sentence in English:

> Suppose that you buy the product in $10 in the store A. The store A is located in 3 miles away.
>
> **Now**, you found out that the store B sells the same item in $8. But it is located in 8 miles away.

In this usage of *now*, an adverb to draw attention to a particular statement or point in a narrative, how can I express it in Chinese?

The most basic word to express "now" in 现在, but I feel it is exclusively used in the situation that specifically refers to the time, not in the way that draws attention to a particular statement.

So what word, or phrase is suitable in Chinese in these cases? Or is it commont to use such expression in Chinese as well, or if not, what is the more natural way to draw attention to a particular statement in Chinese?

Comment: users suggest searching "now" in online dictionaries or "now 中文＂on the web as a whole, iciba, e.g. seems to supply an answer: now adv.

现在； 其时； 立刻； **（改变话题或要对方做某事前，引起对方注意）喂** , bkrs: 喂 (2) interjection to call attention 用于引起注意或鼓动 [hey]。 表示疑问、 惊奇或狂喜, 或用于歌曲的叠句中, 无明确意义。 如: 喂, 你的围巾快掉了

Comment: I'd just say 那么，but I'm not a native speaker neither an extremely advanced learner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, you found out that the store B sells the same item in $8. But it is located in 8 miles away.

I am not a native English speaker, but I don't quite agree that **now** here means *draw attention to a particular statement or point in a narrative*. In my opinion, it means this sense in this context:

> ADV You say "Now" to introduce something which contrasts with what you have just said. 然而
>
> Now, if it was me, I'd want to do more than just change the locks.
>
> 然而，如果是我，我要做的远不只是换换锁。

I think there should be an implicit *but* in your English sentence. So, you could interpret that *now* as *可是现在, 然而现在*，or just simply as 然而，可是.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following as a proclamation to draw attention to the second statement which is stated **after** the first one

现在(now), 接下來(and then), 可是(however), 之後(afterward) , 但是 (but)

They all work in your example

Answer (score 1):

但是 and 可是 would work best. Read [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Two_words_for_%22but%22) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question! I don't think there is a simple, fits-all-situations answer. This use of now is strange and idiomatic in English. I think that it often will not be translated.

In this particular situation I would use ‘但是’。

Some examples of these idiomatic uses of 'now'.

Now, let me think.
那（么），让我想一想。

Now come on, tell me!
快告诉我吧！

Don’t forget now!
不要忘了！

Now that’s what I like, sunshine and blue sky! 
这就是我喜欢的，阳光和蓝天！

Now understand, you only get one bite at the cherry!
你得弄清楚，你只有一次机会!

Now hear this， now hear this! (official public / military announcement / warning)
请注意

The first problem is solved, now the next problem is .....
第一个问题解决了，那么下一个问题就是 ....

Come on now, don't be angry.
别生气了。

Run along now. （friendly, not unkind)
你到旁边去吧。

Now, if you'll excuse me?
如果你已经说完的话，我还有别的事要处理。

Now, where did  I put my glasses
我又把眼镜放在哪儿？

Suppose that you buy the product for $10 in store A. The store A is located 3 miles away.
假设你以10美元的价格在A商店买下这款产品。商店A在三英里外的地方。

Now, you found out that the store B sells the same item for $8, but it is located 8 miles away.
但是你发现在商店B可以买到同样的物品,价格只是八美元，可是商店B在八英里外的地方。

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, 然后 would fit best. But it's not a general translation that answers your main question.